# MomentJs. When time is converted why does it always output the hour with :10 as minutes?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert time from a date and was testing why it was always coming out as 11:10. I set up this simple test to see if it was still converting the same way and it is. This test gives start time formatted as 11:10. It should be 11:59.

```
var testDate = "11:59"
console.log("start time formatted", moment(testDate, ["h:mm"]).format("H:MM"));
console.log("start time", testDate);
```

Comment: You format minutes as a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `MM` is numeric format for month which is current month October (10). Try to change it to `mm` like following code.

```
moment(testDate, ["h:mm"]).format("H:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, MM and mm are differences for month and minutes!

```
var testDate = "11:50"
console.log("start time formatted", moment(testDate, ["h:m"]).format("H:mm"));
console.log("start time", testDate);
```